# Interrupted Finder whilst it was deleting 400GB of files. Now I have 400GB of Hidden Space that won't go away

Tags: finder, trash, macos

[image: Daisy Disk Snapshot]

I was in the process of deleting 400GB of files from the Trash when I needed to restart Finder.

The Trash emptying progress bar was about 1/3rd of the way through.

Now DaisyDisk tells me I have 400GB of Hidden Space on a 1TB SSD.

I've restarted, waited a few days, and the space has not become available again.

Is there anything else I can do to reclaim this space?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would help if you force-delete any remaining files from the .Trash folder using the terminal. I found this site to have a useful step-by-step tutorial of how it is done:

https://www.imore.com/how-force-empty-trash-your-mac-using-terminal

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Catch is, the Trash appears empty when viewed in Finder

Answer (score 0):

So...9 days and 2 airtaskers later, the system has fixed itself overnight.

The space has been reclaimed without me doing anything.

Just took a very long time.